# Unable to create Build on Docker Hub from GitHub

Tags: docker, github, dockerhub

I just created a new account on hub.docker.com. I successfully linked my GitHub account in settings. After I clicked on `Create Repository`, I am presented with the familiar screen, where I can create a new docker repository. However, the first strange thing here I noticed is, that I don't have the additional build options.

**This is what is missing:**

[image: I don't see this section when attempting to create a new repository]

I went on and created a blank repository. After that I went to the builds tab and clicked on the GitHub button, which said I was connected:
[image]

In the following screen, I can select the the desired repository. After filling out the remainder of the form, nothing happens after I click `Save` or `Save and Build`.
I do not see any error messages popping up either.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong with this newly created docker account?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GitHub, I'd recommend [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action) for setting up a connection with GitHub Actions and Docker.

I've only set up a connection with BitBucket and Docker, but I'll share the process with BitBucket for anyone else searching, or in case that provides any additional insight that might help with GitHub.

In BitBucket, you need to set up a pipeline to push the build to the repo. [The docs here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/build-and-push-a-docker-image-to-a-container-registry/) outline the process.

A quick summary of the steps in BitBucket:

1. Go to your repo in bit bucket
2. Click on pipelines and add the Docker template
3. Update the image name in the yml template
4. Commit the yml to the repo
5. Set up the variables in the repository settings in BitBucket for your credentials and repo slug
6. Check the status of your build in the pipelines tab, it should automatically rebuild up update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Steve! I don't have my code on BitBucket. I will look into [Github's Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), maybe this will work for me. Otherwise I will pull my code into BitBucket :-)

Comment: Ahh apologies @jrn, I misread your questions there. I haven't integrated with github before, but actions sound like the right answer to me, this guide may also be helpful: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action

I'll edit my answer to reflect this too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works for me now with GitHub :-)